# Como fazer abas tipo a do chrome

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como eu crio abas tipo a do Chrome. Eu pensei com o `TabControl` mas não tem como colocar o botão de fechar aba e nova aba. Como eu faço?

PS: Quero fazer um standalone para um jogo que possa abrir mais de uma guia para poder jogar. É uma aplicação desktop. (WindowsForms)

Comment: Mas qual é a ideia? Projeto web ou desktop? E o usuário ao clicar em 'nova aba', qual será o conteúdo da mesma?  E por qual necessidade o usuário vai querer fechar alguma aba do sistema?

Comment: Um carinha ensina como criar abas com Menu, Multiview e View com CSS, vÊ se te ajuda:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-criar-abas-em-asp-net-usando-menu-multiview-e-view-com-css/7061

Comment: Você precisa desenvolver seus próprios controles de usuário.

Comment: Olá, meu jovem!
Tenho um projeto usando o User Control, com ele você pode criar os seus próprios .Net Componentes Deixo aqui dois links: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Usando-o-User-Control-para-6d090bca
e:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Navegador-Com-Abas-Sem-84048dd8 Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro estudar a criação dos próprios controles, existe um bom projeto no CodeProject para isto:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition

No caso da ação de criar e remover abas é necessário implementar o OnClick de um controle customizado (UserControl ou Control) à parte (anexo às guias):

```
public partial class AddTabButton : UserControl
{
    public AddTabButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // override on OnPaint ou OnClick para adicionar funcionalidades e efeitos
}
```

O mesmo se aplica à remoção de uma guia, você precisa criar um controle customizado (UserControl) onde o mesmo é composto de 2 itens: Texto e um botão fechar, este botão você provavelmente gostaria de implementar seu próprio desenho (no caso uma classe como CloseTabButton semelhante à superior).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É necessário também criar o compositor das guias (que armazena a coleção de guias, controla as posições adequadas, etc).

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomTabCompositeGroup : UserControl
{
    IList<CustomTab> tabs = new List<CustomTab>();

    public CustomTabCompositeGroup()
    {

    }

    public void AddTab(CustomTab tab)
    {
        this.tabs.Add(tab);
        this.OnTabCollectionChanged();
        // Adicionar evento OnClick ao botão + da guia
    }

    private void OnTabCollectionChanged()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabs.Count; i++)
        {
            // TODO: posição da tab


        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

O resto se trata de desenho na tela, basicamente você sobrescreve o método OnPaint e desenha sua própria guia:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class CustomTab : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: desenhar sua guia

        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

        graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(), new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Right - 1, 0));

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

os métodos necessários para se desenhar a guia estão aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.100).ASPX

Por quê tudo isso? Bom, o Windows tem sua própria implementação das Tabs, caso queira criar a sua deve seguir o mesmo caminho do Chrome, partir do "quase zero".

Observação: Criar um controle de guias customizado é uma tarefa árdua, especialmente com a funcionalidade semelhante ao Google Chrome onde as guias podem flutuar sobre a barra e se deslocar para uma nova janela, o código das Tabs do Chrome está localizado aqui e é extenso:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/branches/2105/src/chrome/browser/ui/tabs/

2105 é o Branch do projeto